# Retrieved the checked items from a CheckedListBox VB.NET Winform

Tags: vb.net

I asked this question before but suggested to provide a more details. Here is the problem:

1. I have a CheckedListBox called `CheckedList_Facility`.  All items in this `CheckedList_Facility` are getting from SQL Server Datasource. All items are loaded properly using the below code

   ```
   Dim queryString As String = "SELECT Facility FROM Database.dbo.Facility "
   Dim connection As New SqlConnection(connectionString)
   Dim command As New SqlCommand(queryString, connection)
   connection.Open()
   Dim dataReader As SqlDataReader = command.ExecuteReader()
   Dim source As New BindingSource
   source.DataSource = dataReader
   CheckedList_Facility.DataSource = source
   CheckedList_Facility.ValueMember = "Facility"
   connection.Close()
   ```
2. I would like to get a list of items that are checked. For example,

   [X] AAA

   [X] BBB

   [ ] CCC

   [ ] DDD

   [X] EEE

then the list should be "AAA", "BBB", "EEE"

1. To test if the item is retrieved correctly, I using a button call `bt_GetItem` and when this button is pressed, a msgbox displays the items that are checked. With this code:

   ```
   Dim itemChecked As Object
   For Each itemChecked In CheckedList_Facility.CheckedItems
       MsgBox(itemChecked.ToString)
   Next
   ```
2. However, I only receive this error message

   **System.Data.Common.DataRecordInternal**

Technically, this might not be an error but instead of receiving "AAA", I get this

```
System.Data.Common.DataRecordInternal
```

Comment: At what line do you get this error?

Comment: @Winks - technically it is not an error but instead of getting "AAA", I got "System.Data.Common.DataRecordInternal" displays on the msgbox

Comment: I'm going to try to recreate the problem

Comment: What if you do `MsgBox(itemChecked.Facility.ToString)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because you bound the checkedlistbox to your datareader, the checked object internally is actually a `{System.Data.Common.DataRecordInternal}` and not a string or any other native object.
You have to access the `item` property within the object to get to the string you want, like so:

```
 MsgBox(itemChecked.item("Facility").ToString)
```

Answer (score 4):

In order for your "AAA" (*type of string*) to be displayed you must access the `itemChecked` object's property. Since you're selecting "Facility" we'll use that. The message you were receiving (**System.Data.Common.DataRecordInternal**) was the object `itemChecked` type.

```
MsgBox(itemChecked.Items("Facility").ToString)
```

Should output "AAA"

Answer (score 0):

```
For i As Integer = 0 To lbSit.Items.Count - 1
    If CType(lbSit.Items(i), DataRowView)(lbSit.ValueMember).ToString = "32" Then
        lbSit.SetItemChecked(i, True)
    End If
Next
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding _how_ and/or _why_ it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Answer (score 0):

```
Private Sub WhatIsChecked_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles WhatIsChecked.Click
    ' Display in a message box all the items that are checked.
    Dim indexChecked As Integer
    Dim itemChecked As Object
    Const quote As String = """"

    ' First show the index and check state of all selected items.
    For Each indexChecked In CheckedListBox1.CheckedIndices
        ' The indexChecked variable contains the index of the item.
        MessageBox.Show("Index#: " + indexChecked.ToString() + ", is checked. Checked state is:" + _
                        CheckedListBox1.GetItemCheckState(indexChecked).ToString() + ".")
    Next

    ' Next show the object title and check state for each item selected.
    For Each itemChecked In CheckedListBox1.CheckedItems

        ' Use the IndexOf method to get the index of an item.
        MessageBox.Show("Item with title: " + quote + itemChecked.ToString() + quote + _
                        ", is checked. Checked state is: " + _
                        CheckedListBox1.GetItemCheckState(CheckedListBox1.Items.IndexOf(itemChecked)).ToString() + ".")
    Next
```