# Why I can't access Item property within the object so I can get the string I want?

Tags: vb.net, checkedlistbox

I am trying to use the CheckedListBox to select multiple employees and I am trying the get the `ID`(value member). I followed [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17576340/retrieved-the-checked-items-from-a-checkedlistbox-vb-net-winform) question with answer with almost the same principle as mine but with different way of binding my source to my CheckedListBox.

Now my problem is I want to get the `ID` but I cannot access the `Item` property as stated in the selected answer of the question. Why I cant access it?

My code for making/getting the list of `Employee`

```
Private Sub frmLogs_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    'Get the employee list from employee table
    Dim xemployees = (From x In MyContext.Employees
                      Where x.Status = True
                      Select New With {
                     .ID = x.EID,
                     .Name = x.Lastname & ", " & x.Firstname}).ToList
    employees = xemployees.OrderBy(Function(x) x.Name).ToList()
```

Populating my CheckedListBox

```
Sub LoadCBL()
    CBL_Employee.DataSource = employees
    CBL_Employee.DisplayMember = "Name"
    CBL_Employee.ValueMember = "ID"
End Sub
```

Button, to show/get the selected items' ID

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnCBL.Click
        Dim itemChecked As Object
        For Each itemChecked In CBL_Employee.CheckedItems
            MsgBox(itemChecked.item("ID"))
        Next
End Sub
```

The error I get `Public member 'item' on type 'VB$AnonymousType_9(Of Integer,String)' not found.`

Answer (score 1):

You are binding a `List(Of T)` to your control, where `T` is an anonymous type with properties `ID` and `Name`.  That means that each item in the `CheckedListBox` is an object of that type `T`.  The `CheckedItems` property of the control is a collection of the items in the control that are checked in the UI.  If it contains items from the control then it contains objects of that same type `T`.

That means that, in your last code snippet, `itemChecked` is an object of type `T`, so it has properties `ID` and `Name`.  You seem to be under the misapprehension that it is some other type that has an `Item` property that is type `T`.  That is not correct.

The bad news is that the `CheckedListBox` simply doesn't provide the functionality you want.  Just as with a `ComboBox` or `ListBox`, you can use the `SelectedValue` to get a single value from the property or column specified in the `ValueMember` but there is no functionality to get multiple such values.  The good news is that you can provide such functionality yourself.  What's more, I've already done so.  To get the full story, check out my post [here](http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?851021)

For the abridged version, you can define your own type that inherits `CheckedListBox` and provides a method to get the value for an item in much the same way as `GetItemText` gets the text for an item:

```
Public Class CheckedListBoxEx
    Inherits CheckedListBox

    Public Function GetItemValue(item As Object) As Object
        Dim index = Me.Items.IndexOf(item)

        If (index <> -1 AndAlso Me.DataManager IsNot Nothing) Then
            Return Me.FilterItemOnProperty(Me.DataManager.List(index), Me.ValueMember)
        End If

        Return Nothing
    End Function

End Class
```

You can then get the value for each checked item like so:

```
For Each checkedItem As Object In CheckedListBoxEx1.CheckedItems
    MessageBox.Show(CheckedListBoxEx1.GetItemValue(checkedItem).ToString())
Next
```

Much as you would use the `SelectedValue` like this to get a single `ID` value:

```
Dim id = CInt(CheckedListBoxEx1.SelectedValue)
```

you could do this to get the `ID` values for all the checked items:

```
Dim ids = CheckedListBoxEx1.CheckedItems.
                            Cast(Of Object)().
                            Select(Function(o) CInt(CheckedListBoxEx1.GetItemValue(o))).
                            ToArray()
```

You could even build such functionality into your control:

```
Public ReadOnly Property SelectedValues As Object()
    Get
        Return SelectedItems.Cast(Of Object)().
                             Select(Function(o) GetItemValue(o)).
                             ToArray()
    End Get
End Property

Public ReadOnly Property CheckedValues As Object()
    Get
        Return CheckedItems.Cast(Of Object)().
                            Select(Function(o) GetItemValue(o)).
                            ToArray()
    End Get
End Property
```

Because those properties return an `Object` array, you'd still have to cast as type `Integer` in your case:

```
Dim ids = CheckedListBoxEx1.CheckedValues.
                            Cast(Of Integer)().
                            ToArray()
```

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. I really appreciated it.